# How to show all tagsvalues in a plot using python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

This is a sample of my dataframe:

```
carParkDetailsUrl   id  name    $type   bayType bayCount    free    occupied    perc_free   perc_occup
0   Place\CarParks_800491   CarParks_800491 Barkingside Stn (LUL)   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Bay, Tfl.Api.Pre...   Disabled    2.0 1.0 1.0 50.000000   50.000000
1   Place\CarParks_800468   CarParks_800468 Buckhurst Hill Stn (LUL)    Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Bay, Tfl.Api.Pre...   Disabled    2.0 1.0 1.0 50.000000   50.000000
2   Place\CarParks_800475   CarParks_800475 Fairlop Stn (LUL)   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Bay, Tfl.Api.Pre...   Disabled    2.0 0.0 2.0 0.000000    100.00000
```

And this is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a4_dims = (20, 10)
df_new1.plot.bar(x = 'name', y = ['perc_free', 'perc_occup'], rot = 40, figsize=a4_dims, fontsize=10)
ax.set_xlabel("Parking places")
```

And this is my graph:
[image: Bar graph]

Comment: Try to create a [mcve] that can be copied from your question and run. State which versions of the libraries you use.

Comment: I changed the rot to 90 and it worked. Thanks